# how to validate drop down menu in react js

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to validate a basic form in reactjs which contains select dropdown box.i'm new to react and not able to figure out the correct tutorial.please suggest.

```
<select required className = "custom form-group" name = "workFlow" 
        value = {this.state.result.workflow}
        required onChange = { this.handleChange} > 
  {
    data.map((data1) => {
      return <option key={data1.id}>{data1.workType}
      </option>;
    })
  }
</select>
```

i am fetching data from a json file and i need to made this select field as mandatory

Comment: code indentation

Answer (score 1):

Using the "required" attribute with a  element

- you must have at least one child element
- the first child element must have either an empty value attribute OR
- the first child element must have no text content.

Other than that if you want to make use of event handlers then check the data that you received from the form in the onSubmit form Handler and then by making use of state display the error message or if check pass then submit the request to server.

Hope this help you out.